# Powershell: How to switch DEBUG and Information logging at command line

Tags: powershell, logging

I am using PowerShell 5.1.18362.145. I have a very simple script in a file:

```
 Write-Verbose "This is verbose"  
 Write-Debug("This is debug")  
 Write-Information("This is information")  
 Write-Warning "This is warning"
```

When I execute this script in Powershell ISE, I only get (what I expected) the warning.
If I execute the script with either `-DEBUG` or `-InformationAction` Continue, I still only get the warning message.
To get the other logging messages, I have to set the preference variable accordingly. I thought this was unnecessary as the command line switch overrides the variable.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your script will not have the `-Debug` or `-InformationAction` switches by default. You have to specify, at the very least, the below code at the top of ur script for those to be active.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
```